# Configuration String with Null DefaultValue

Tags: c#, .net, string, configuration, app-config

I have the following ConfigurationProperty as part of an element:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("example", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = null)]
public string Example { 
    get { return (string)base["example"]; }
    set { base["example"] = value; }
}
```

If I set it as follows, it takes on the `"Hello"` string and works properly:

```
<myElement example="Hello"/>
```

If it is not present, I run into problems:

```
<myElement/>
```

Instead of taking on the default value of `null` as specified above, it takes on `String.Empty`. Why is that, and how can I get it to take on a default value of `null`?

**Update**

Its definitely because `base["example"]` returns `String.Empty`, where `base` is a `ConfigurationElement` (the indexer is defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8693ks1(v=vs.110).aspx), but I am still not sure why it doesn't take on a value of `null`.

**Update**

Even `DefaultValue = default(string)` sets the string to `String.Empty`.

**Update**

Even `base.Properties.Contains("example")` returns `true` if the property does not exist in the configuration.

Comment: I don't know why `DefaultValue` is not honoured, but have you tried extending the property's getter with a check against `base.Properties.Contains("example")`, and manually returning `null` if false?

Comment: @stakx Thanks for the idea. You're not going to believe this but, even `base.Properties.Contains("example")` returns `true` when a `String` property does not exist in the configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging from the [Reference Source for the `ConfigurationProperty` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationProperty.cs,7eb868f3d72355a4), this is perhaps not a bug, but a feature.

Here is the relevant internal method, `InitDefaultValueFromTypeInfo` (with some minor formatting modifications by me):

> ```
> private void InitDefaultValueFromTypeInfo(ConfigurationPropertyAttribute attribProperty,
>                                           DefaultValueAttribute attribStdDefault) {
>      object defaultValue = attribProperty.DefaultValue;
>
>      // If there is no default value there - try the other attribute ( the clr standard one )
>      if ((defaultValue == null || defaultValue == ConfigurationElement.s_nullPropertyValue) &&
>          (attribStdDefault != null)) {
>          defaultValue = attribStdDefault.Value;
>      }
>
>      // If there was a default value in the prop attribute - check if we need to convert it from string
>      if ((defaultValue != null) && (defaultValue is string) && (_type != typeof(string))) {
>          // Use the converter to parse this property default value
>          try {
>              defaultValue = Converter.ConvertFromInvariantString((string)defaultValue);
>          }
>          catch (Exception ex) {
>              throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(SR.GetString(SR.Default_value_conversion_error_from_string, _name, ex.Message));
>          }
>      }
>
>      if (defaultValue == null || defaultValue == ConfigurationElement.s_nullPropertyValue) {
>          if (_type == typeof(string)) {
>              defaultValue = String.Empty;
>          }
>          else if (_type.IsValueType) {
>              defaultValue = TypeUtil.CreateInstanceWithReflectionPermission(_type);
>          }
>      }
>
>      SetDefaultValue(defaultValue);
>  }
> ```

The last `if` block is interesting: If your property has type `string`, and the default value is `null`, then the default value gets changed to `string.Empty`.

The first `if` block hints at a possible explanation for this peculiar behaviour. The `[ConfigurationProperty]` attribute's `DefaultValue` property is optional. If `DefaultValue` is not set by the programmer, then it defaults `null` itself. The first `if` block uses that default `null` to check whether a `DefaultValue` was specified. If not, it falls back to fetching a default value from a `[DefaultValue]` attribute, if such a one present.

This all means: Specifying `DefaultValue = null` has the same effect as not specifying it at all, and in that case, the configuration sub-system chooses a "sane" default value for strings: the empty string.

#### Workaround:

Here is a somewhat hacky workaround: Don't declare your configuration property as `string`, but as a thin wrapper type around string; then declare a suitable type converter:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = false)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(IncognitoStringConverter))]  // note: additional attribute!
public IncognitoString Name                        // note: different property type
{
    get
    {
        return (IncognitoString)base["name"];
    }
    set
    {
        base["name"] = value;
    }
}
```

Here are the implementations for `IncognitoString` and `IncognitoStringConverter`:

```
public struct IncognitoString
{
    private IncognitoString(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private readonly string value;

    public static implicit operator IncognitoString(string value)
    {
        return new IncognitoString(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(IncognitoString incognitoString)
    {
        return incognitoString.value;
    }

    … // perhaps override ToString, GetHashCode, and Equals as well.
}

public sealed class IncognitoStringConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return (IncognitoString)(string)value;
    }
}
```

Because `IncognitoString` is implicitly convertible to `string`, you can assign the property value to any string variable. I know, it's hacky and really complicated just to get nullable properties. Perhaps just live with the empty string.

Comment: Best answer I've seen to any of my questions circa 2014 to 2015! :D

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to make a call something like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("Prompt")]
public string Prompt
{
    get { return this.GetNullableStringValue("Prompt"); }
}

private string GetNullableStringValue(string propertyName)
{
    return (string)this[new ConfigurationProperty(propertyName, typeof(string), null)];
}
```

Calling `GetNullableString` like this bypasses the configuration property attribute and stops it defaulting the DefaultValue to null. You could put the method in a base class too to make it a bit tidier.

You just have to remember that you are calling it if you want to change the default.

You could also put in a call to `this.ElementInformation.Properties[propertyName]` if you wanted to lift some of the other things you might define on the attribute - just don't use that to populate `DefaultValue`

Comment: Thanks, this is great.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking the property value for `null` you can easily check if the property has been set in the configuration file or the default value has been returned. This can be done be looking at the `ValueOrigin` in the `ConfigurationElement`'s `ElementInformation`.

```
// if not the default value...    
if (MyConfigurationElement.ElementInformation.Properties["example"].ValueOrigin!=
        PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
{
    ...
}
```

See also the documentation of the values of the [PropertyValueOrigin Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.propertyvalueorigin(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigurationElement` type has an `ElementInformation` property which in turn has an `IsPresent` property.

So, rather then trying to return a null `ConfigurationElement`, you can check the `IsPresent` property to see "whether the associated ConfigurationElement object is in the configuration file." [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.elementinformation(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example:

```
if (Configuration.Example.ElementInformation.IsPresent)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer and should be marked as solution

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use a more readable and reusable extension method `ToNullIfEmpty()`. I left the DefaultValue in place in case there is ever a change to the non-intuitive behavior that converts null strings to String.Empty.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("dataCenterRegion", DefaultValue = null)]
public string DataCenterRegion
{
    get { return ((string)this["dataCenterRegion"]).ToNullIfEmpty(); }
    set { this["dataCenterRegion"] = value; }
}

public static partial class ExtensionMethods
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Return null if the string is empty or is already null.
    /// Otherwise, return the original string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToNullIfEmpty(this string str)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? null : str;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return null if the string is white space, empty or is already null.
    /// Otherwise, return the original string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToNullIfWhiteSpaceOrEmpty(this string str)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? null : str;
    }
}
```